# FTP client in a docker container

Tags: python, ftp, docker

I'm trying to connect to an FTP server programmatically. The language of my choice is Python, which is simple enough:

```
from ftplib import FTP
ftp = FTP(host=FTP_HOST, user=FTP_USERNAME, passwd=FTP_PASSWORD)
ftp.dir()
```

If I run these three lines on my local machine, it returns a filelist (nlst works as well, as a sidenote). If I now run my Docker container, enter it (docker exec), and go to python, and try to run the same three commands there, it produces a timeout.

I originally suspected it has something to do with the ports, so I exposed port 21, and instructed ftplib to operate over the exposed port, but this gave the same behaviour.

Does anyone have an idea on how to figure out why it works fine locally, but refuses in a container?

EDIT: I'm using passive FTP, and the server is not running on my local machine.

Comment: Possibly active vs passive FTP. Active FTP requires the client (Docker container) to open data ports in addition to 21 so is not practical. Verify using passive FTP in Python.

Comment: And where is the target FTP server? Docker will not be able to access ports on the same host by default.

Comment: I'm using passive FTP (which appears to be the default in ftplib), and the server is not running on my local machine or even my network.

Comment: @Peleion *Docker will not be able to access ports on the same host by default.* Uh? It's fairly frequent to have several containers talk to each other (docker-compose, Kubernetes pods...)

Comment: Absolutely correct and a huge feature but talking to other containers on a Docker network is different from talking to the host ports directly

Answer (score 1):

The problem has not been found, but it does appear to be limited to Docker on Windows. The same container works fine on other systems. Under windows, there is communication between the client and the server, and the server responds just fine, but actually transferring files/data results in a timeout.

Answer (score 1):

I happened to run into the same issue, I was able to access FTP when executing code in a venv on my dev machine. However it timed out when the same code executes in a docker container on the same machine (Docker desktop for windows). I got it to work by accessing the FTP site via public IP address.